# Why is createLocalVue needed when testing Vue components with Vuex?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuex, vue-test-utils

I'm reading through the [Vue Testing Cookbook](https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/vuex-in-components.html#using-createlocalvue-to-test-store-state) and [Vue Test Utils's docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html), where they touch on testing components with Vuex. Both sources advise using `createLocalVue`, but I don't fully understand why. We already have a couple of tests that use Vuex but don't use `createLocalVue`, and they work. **So why do these sources suggest using `createLocalVue`?**

Here's the test that appears to be a bad practice according to those sources. Is this code going to break something down the road? Is it causing unwanted side-effects we're not aware of?

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Component from 'somewhere';

// We don't use this and yet the code seems to work
// const localVue = createLocalVue()
// localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('Foo Component', () => {
    let wrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(Component, {
            // localVue, <-- We don't use this
            store: new Vuex.Store({
                modules: {
                    app: {
                        namespaced: true,
                        // ... more store stuff
                    }
                }
            }) 
        })
    });

    it('should contain foo', () => {
        expect(wrapper.contains('.foo')).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#localvue):

> **localVue**: A local copy of Vue created by `createLocalVue` to use when mounting the component. Installing plugins on this copy of Vue prevents polluting the original Vue copy.

In your tests, you might want to make particular changes and install plugins on the tested Vue instance. Using `localVue` ensures those changes are reset for every test.

An obvious advantage is you don't have to install all plugins for all tests. So your tests will be faster.

Also, when your tests get a bit more complex, if you don't use `localVue` you'll experience tests failing erratically based on their order, because the previously ran test, even though it passed, modified the Vue instance in a way that breaks your next test. But the next test passes when ran in isolation.
The type of errors which typically imply hair loss.

Using `localVue` provides a type of certainty most developers welcome when running tests. If you feel adventurous, don't use it.

It's a recommendation, not an imposition.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what sort of sequence of tests would fail? I’m creating a new store in each test.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. I only experienced this type of errors more than 1 year ago, on one of the more complex Vue projects I worked on. Since it forced us to raise the bar on our coding standards, we haven't experienced this type of errors lately, so I don't have a practical example at hand.

Comment: But what I can assure you is that it was because I was using the same Vue prototype and once I started using `localVue` i got rid of those errors. The symptoms were quite easy to describe: tests were passing when ran in isolation but failing when ran in sequence.

Comment: I'm curious if this is specific to particular testing harnesses that don't start new sessions for each test. But we should probably adopt the best practice regardless, in case we switch to a new test harness.